# Testing Apple Smart App Banner on desktop browser

Tags: ios, safari, user-agent

Is there any way of testing Apple Smart App Banners in a desktop browser by doing something along the line of spoofing the user agent, or is this functionality so specific to Mobile Safari that I can only test it on an iDevice?

I know that merely spoofing the user agent in a desktop browser doesn't do anything in regards to showing the Smart App Banner, but maybe I can do something else in my desktop Safari browser to test the banner?

I am not an iOS developer but I have access to the iOS emulator on my colleague's Mac if that helps.

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately, the Smart App Banner is only displayed on iOS Safari *on a real device*.  The [iOS Simulator](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002051-CH6-SW5) and desktop Safari cannot display smart app banners.

This is a bummer, especially because resetting smart app banners after they have been dismissed is a [huge pain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412838/smart-app-banners-do-not-appear-after-being-closed-on-ipad-with-ios7).

Answer (score 1):

In chrome dev tools, click the sprocket that lead you to the more advnaced settings, there check the 'override' check-box, and select a mobile user agent(IOS, Android).

Keep in mind that the screen sizes that chrome provide are not always accurate and might need some adjustment.

For more accurate screen sizes you might want to use Mozilla & Firebug(basically has the same functionality)

Answer (score -3):

You can just tap the toggle device toolbar inside chrome inspector and the smart app banners are recognized since this toggle changes to a mobile user agent.

See sample result : 
[image]