# Smart banner for iOS not work only for my app id

Tags: ios, iphone, smartbanner

I added the following meta to my html file, it works fine if the app-id is the AppStore app id, but the banner does not show up if I replace it with own app id. This only happen on an iPhone 4s with iOS7.1. Both work fine on my iPhone 5 with iOS7.1.

Is it a bug for iPhone 4s with iOS7.1 ?

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=xxxxxxxxx"/>
```

Comment: I also tried to clear cookies but still doesn't work. I am sure that my app is available in my country and iPhone4s

Comment: possible duplicate of [Smart app banners do not appear after being closed on iPad with IOS7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412838/smart-app-banners-do-not-appear-after-being-closed-on-ipad-with-ios7)

Answer (score 1):

The most probable cause is that you've already closed the smart banner. Once closed, it won't appear again (at least for a while). Try clearing the cookies on your phone (settings -> Safari ->  Clear Cookies and Data). Safari sets a cookie after closing the smart banner so this should clear out the cookie in question.

Other possible solutions:

- The app isn't available to download in your country.
- The app can't be run on your phone. Although, given that you said you're using a 4S, I don't think there's any way of doing this (on the other hand, you could stop an app running on iPhone 4 by requiring Bluetooth LE).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did clear the cookie before but still don't work. and I am sure my app is available in my country and also can be run on my phone.

Answer (score -1):

Chances are, you've pressed the X button on the smart banner at some point. In order to get it back, clearing your Safari website data isn't enough, you need to reset all settings on your phone.

Go to:

- Settings app
- General
- Reset
- Reset all settings

This will show the smart banner again

Comment: This will delete all your phone's settings, not just safari

Comment: Yes, as I said in the answer, "you need to reset all settings on your phone"