# how to check if smart app banner is closed

Tags: ios, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile, safari, mobile-safari

i have a jquery mobile application, in iOS safari a smart app banner comes when the application is loaded in the browser that tells to install or open the application. ones the smart app banner is closed by the x icon in the prompt then its told that the safari sets a flag with the particular app id which is passed with the meta tag.

is there any way that we can get the set flag details ?
or 
is there any way we can know if the x icon is clicked ?

[image]

the banner shown in the image is smart app banner and ones we click the x icon in that banner then the banner never prompts for that particular app. when i searched about this it was told that a flag will be set by safari for that particular app with the app id we specify in the meta tag for the smart app banner. i need to know, is there any way to get the flag details, or to reset the flag.

the only solution i found to reset the flag is to reset the device

Comment: could you take a look to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask also I would prefer code, screenshots and more details to be precise

Comment: i have update the details with image, kindly go through.

Comment: the image now is loaded in the question not a link, but still, I can't understand what exactly your problem

Comment: Is it related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412838/smart-app-banners-do-not-appear-after-being-closed-on-ipad-with-ios7?rq=1

Comment: yes it is but is there any other way around to see if is closed or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to window resize event. It will be emitted after a banner has been closed.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', () => ...);
```