# iOS Universal link not working in react-native iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, deep-linking, ios-universal-links, universal-link

Hi I know this question being asked before still I cannot figure out what am doing wrong.

1. Added apple-app-site-association file in our server under https://ourserver.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association
2. The file content is as follows

`

```
{
   "applinks":{
      "apps":[],
      "details":[
         {
            "appID":"<teamId>.<bundleId>",
            "paths":[ "*",  "/" ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

`
3. Associated Domain is added as capability with

```
 applinks:servername.com
 applinks:dev.servername.com
```

4. Added code in AppDeletegate.m

   ```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
    openURL:(NSURL *)url
    options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
   {
     return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url options:options];
    }


   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(nonnull NSUserActivity *)userActivity
    restorationHandler:(nonnull void (^)(NSArray<id<UIUserActivityRestoring>> * _Nullable))restorationHandler
   {
    return [RCTLinkingManager application:application
                 continueUserActivity:userActivity
                   restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
   }
   ```

**EDIT 1**

Noticed something i tried universal linking in iOS versions 12.4.2 iPhone and it redirected correctly. Where as in iOS version 14 it redirected to our web page. So I updated my apple-app-site-association file as follows

```
{
   "applinks": {
      "details": [
         {
            "appIDs": [
               "teamid.bundleid"
            ],
            "components": [
               {
                  "/": "/*",
                  "comment": "Matches any URL whose path starts with URL_PATH and instructs the system not to open it as a universal link"
               },
               {
                  "/": "*",
                  "comment": "Matches any URL whose path starts with URL_PATH and instructs the system not to open it as a universal link"
               }
            ],
            "paths": [
               "*",
               "/"
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

oru web url is validated in [this link](https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/)

All the testing is done in real devices.

**EDIT 2**

All below is tested in Simulator - iPhone 11 Pro iOS 14.4

1. Tested the same in a simulator with developer mode

   applinks:servername.com?mode=developer
   applinks:dev.servername.com?mode=developer

it opened correctly in SIMUALTOR

2. then i misspelled our server name and clicked from iMessages it   redirected to Safari in SIMULATOR -
3. I tried again with correct server name after clearing Safari history and cache - STILL IT REDIRECTES TO BROWSER NOT APP

**EDIT 3**

On Simulator

Went through this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1916/_index.html) and saw about Smart App banner since i couldn't find anything like that. After searching found this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412838/smart-app-banners-do-not-appear-after-being-closed-on-ipad-with-ios7) and tried Settings - Safari - Advanced - Website Data - In the page showed my domain name - Clear Website Data.
Tried again on Simulator and app opened correctly

On iPhone with release adhoc build

On Real Device did the same Settings - Safari - Advanced - Website Data - In the page showed my domain name - Clear Website Data but it didn't work. Still it opens the browser in app

**EDIT 4**

the AASA file in EDIT 2 make the redirection fail in iOS version 12.4.2. Hence updated it like this

```
{
   "applinks":{
      "apps":[
         
      ],
      "details":[
         {
            "appID":"teamid.bundleid",
            "paths":[
               "*",
               "/"
            ],
            "appIDs":[
               "teamed.bundleid"
            ],
            "components":[
               {
                  "/":"/*"
               },
               {
                  "/":"*"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

After updating to this redirects to app in version 12.4.2 but fails in 14 and above versions. Modified AASA file after going through this [link](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/717)

Any Help is Appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I wonder if the issue was Apple's CDN not picking up your modified AASA file. I have yet to find any guidance/documentation on how to notify the CDN of changes.

Comment: Nope its still having issue. Once I figured out what the issue will post an update here.

Comment: Did you resolve this yet?

Comment: @ZubairAhmed No man.

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same issue and saw above @suja haven't resolved it yet so I thought to post the answer here.

First we need to double-check our `<teamID>.<bundleID>` pattern. Because if our association file doesn't recognize this if it's wrong (even though if we got all other steps correctly).

I found this useful official link and [saw this video carefully](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/717). Also, the video slides can be [seen here in PDF](https://devstreaming-cdn.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2019/717b3lem5m2glj/717/717_whats_new_in_universal_links.pdf)

Actually, they've updated the contents regarding association file, like

1. `appID: string_value` key now turns into `appIDs: array_of_strings`
2. the `paths` key has now been replaced by `components`
3. If you want to test in Simulator during development, then you should use a query parameter `mode=developer` at the end of the matching URL in the Association Domains capability in XCode.
   [image]
4. You cannot use `http://` (like if you are launching your website locally using `localhost:PORT` then you should use some external service to make your localhost available as a public link). In my case, I did use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to mock my localhost as `https://`, also don't forget to allow that ngrok URL in CORS policy, if web services (APIs) are being called from your web pages.
5. `apple-app-site-association` must be in a public folder of your website under subdirectory `.well-known`

Now combine all steps. I was having the same issue since yesterday then I found the above links from the official Apple site to get this done and to understand how exactly Universal link works.

**Most importantly**, if you are testing on Simulator, then please make sure that from your [Apple developer Account](https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/profiles/list) that your development `appID.bundleID` should be exact in the association file.

below is my association file as an example

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "details": [
            {
                "appIDs": [
                    "YOUR_PRODUCTION_TEAM_ID.com.yourapp_bundleID",
                    "YOUR_DEV_TEAM_ID.com.yourapp_bundleID.dev"
                ],
                "components": [
                    {
                        "/": "*",
                        "comment": "Matches any URLs"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And for production, don't forget to add the production URLs in association domains capability, as well as `PROD_appID.PROD_bundleID` in `apple-app-site-association` file. Remember this file should be accessible by apple at

```
https://your-web.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association
```

That's it, and further to play around with query parameters as well as dynamic paths, I would suggest seeing the above PDF link and especially the video on the official Apple site!

Comment: You're confusing appID with teamID... everywhere you say appID, you really mean teamID

Answer (score -2):

Try replacing "appID":".bundleid" with "appID":".bundleid" in your aasa file.

Comment: ??  Please clarify